# Always one checkbox checked = true

Tags: extjs, checkbox

i am have 4 checkbox:

```
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'vbox',
                border: 1,
                defaults: { xtype: 'checkbox', anchor: '100%', margin: '2 0 2 2' },
                items: [
                    { bind: { value: '{allObj.goods}' } },
                    { bind: { value: '{allObj.names}' } },
                    { bind: { value: '{allObj.fires}' } },
                    { bind: { value: '{allObj.counts}' } }
                ]
            },
```

And i am want next: if only one checkbox be:

> checked = true

and other:

> checked = false

, disable this checkbox for checked = false.

Comment: Certainly English is difficult for you. The question is too difficult to understand. Can you please try to reformulate.

Comment: I think you have to use Ext.form.field.Radio instead of checkbox if you want only one to be checked at once.

Comment: This question is unclear. And i am want nex what does that mean ?

Comment: sorry for my English, but this is what i want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44341338/3045654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one checkbox is checked, you want to disallow deselection; and since your code contains bindings, you want to do it with bindings. Here you are:

```
items:[{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    bind: {
        value: '{allObj.goods}', 
        disabled:'{allObj.goods && !allObj.names && !allObj.fires && !allObj.counts}'
    }
},{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    bind: {
        value: '{allObj.names}',
        disabled:'{!allObj.goods && allObj.names && !allObj.fires && !allObj.counts}'
    }
},{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    bind: {
        value: '{allObj.fires}', 
        disabled:'{!allObj.goods && !allObj.names && allObj.fires && !allObj.counts}'
    }
},{
    xtype:'checkbox',
    bind: {
        value: '{allObj.counts}', 
        disabled:'{!allObj.goods && !allObj.names && !allObj.fires && allObj.counts}'
    }
}]
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20rt

On a side note, for better reusability you should not use `defaults.xtype`; there's `defaultType` available for this.

Wrong (albeit *sometimes* working):

```
defaults: { xtype: 'checkbox', margin: '2 0 2 2', ...
```

Correct:

```
defaultType: 'checkbox',
defaults: {
    margin: '2 0 2 2',
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to check only one checkbox at once I think you can use [Ext.field.Radio](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Radio.html), but if you want exactly Ext.field.Checkbox you can do something like it:

```
        listeners: {
            change: function (checkbox, value) {
                if (!value)
                    return;

                Ext.each(
                    checkbox.up('panel').query('checkbox[checked=true]:not([name=' + checkbox.name + '])'),
                    function (checkbox) {
                        checkbox.uncheck();
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20qq).

UPDATE: After reading your question for second time I realize that probably you want to disable all other checkboxes when check any of it. If so you can do something like it:

```
            listeners: {
                change: function (checkbox, value) {
                    var panel = checkbox.up('panel');
                    if (value) {
                        Ext.each(
                            panel.query('checkbox:not([name=' + checkbox.name + '])'),
                            function (checkbox) {
                                checkbox.disable();
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        Ext.each(
                            panel.query('checkbox[disabled=true]'),
                            function (checkbox) {
                                checkbox.enable();
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20qr).